# AWK script to remove lines containing numbers between <=-1.5 and >=1.5 on csv file

Tags: awk

I have tried

```
awk '(NR > 1 ) || ( ($3 <= -1.5) && ( $3 >= 1.5 ) ) ' myfile.txt > myfile2.txt
```

However this isnt working

A snapshot of my data
[image: A snapshot of my data]

Comment: What's the meaning of _"between <=-1.5 and >=1.5"_?

Comment: less than -1.5 fold and greater than 1.5 fold

Comment: Can you show the desired result?

Comment: `NR > 1` is true for all lines after the header. So you're keeping everything except the header.

Comment: soo from the image above, all those entries should be removed.. another example wopuld be all values between -1.5 and 1.5 should be removed?

Comment: It's easier if you describe what you want in terms of which lines to keep rather than which to remove. You can use de Morgan's Laws to invert your condition.

Comment: I need to exclude the header

Comment: Use `&&` to combine the `NR > 1` test, not `||`.

Comment: There is no number `$3` that is at the same time `<=-1.5` and `>=1.5`.

Comment: Im going to give it a go now

Comment: I need to remove, all logfold values larger than -1.5 and but less than 1.5

Comment: please update the question with ... a) replace the image with a textual copy (cut-n-paste) of the first 5-10 lines of the file, b) the (wrong) output generated by your code and c) the (correct) expected output; these go a long way to removing confusion as to what you want to accomplish while also providing us with a set of data we can test with (ie, very few, if any of us are going to take the time to convert an image to textual data we can test with)

Comment: Writing requirements in negative terms (e.g. "remove" instead of "print") always makes it harder to implement those requirements. Instead of "remove lines containing numbers between <=-1.5 and >=1.5" think and state it as "print lines containing numbers..." and then fill in the "..." with whatever it should be as I don't know what "between <=-1.5 and >=1.5" means.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine the `NR > 1` test with the rest using `&&`, not `||`. When you use `cond1 || cond2`, the condition is true if either subcondition is true, so your code keeps all lines after the header.

```
awk 'NR > 1 && ($3 <= -1.5 || $3 >= 1.5)' myfile.txt > myfile2.txt
```

Comment: Iv tried this, However, i want to keep lines where 3 is <-1.5 or >1.5

Comment: That's the opposite of what your question title says.

Comment: awk 'NR > 1 && $2 < -1.5 || $2 > 1.5  ' myfile.txt > myfile1.txt i came up with this

Comment: Apologies -- for the title